# Is there a way to not generate a file via CSV Helper?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

If the any opportunity to not generate csv file in system?
I don't wanna to store it in my application and can we generate it smth on fly?
As return I want to converted csv to base64.

```
    var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.csv");
    await using var writer = new StreamWriter(path);
    await using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        await csv.WriteRecordsAsync(list);
    }

    var bytes = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: You already wrote the relevant code - that `StreaWriter` can write to any stream, including MemoryStream

Comment: As for Base64 ... why? If the text is US-English you gain nothing. If it's Unicode, well, so are C#, Javascript, Java, Python, Go strings, API responses and almost all HTML pages like this one.

Comment: Use a `MemoryStream` instead of a file.

Comment: @Anthony14 why do you want Base64? A CSV file is just a text file. It shouldn't need any conversion.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to save it in db and the logic based on storing base64 strings

Comment: @Anthony14 are you sure? Because BASE64 is just text. And CSV is just text

Comment: @Anthony14 BASE64 would make some sense if you wanted to store binary data as text. All databases have binary fields though, so that's not very useful. Text files though are *already* text. There's no reason to encode them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `StreamWriter` can write to any stream, including a `MemoryStream`:

```
using var ms=new MemoryStream();
using var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);

...
return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.GetBuffer());
```

CSV files are text files though, so converting them to BASE64 isn't very useful. StreamWriter uses UTF8 encoding by default so it already handles any language.

It would be better to keep the text as *text*, especially if it's going to be stored in a text field in a database. This can be done by reading the bytes using a `StreamReader`

```
using var reader=new StreamReader(ms);
ms.Position=0;
var csvText=reader.ReadToEnd();
```

var csvText